# C/C++ Socket Programmming - No source available for "ntdll!KiFastSystemCallRet()"

Tags: c++, c, sockets

I started learning socket programming using winsock since I would like to create client-server communication over TCP protocol in C language.

When building my server side program in Eclipse I get error at the line when socket is being created. The error in compiler says: No source available for "ntdll!KiFastSystemCallRet()".

I have added included the Ws2_32.lib and tried the code on winsdos 7 (64 bit) as well as windows xp (32 bit) and still get the same error?

Server side code:

```
/*
    Create a TCP socket
*/

#include<stdio.h>
#include<winsock2.h>

#pragma comment(lib,"ws2_32.lib") //Winsock Library 

int main(int argc , char *argv[])
{
    WSADATA wsa;
    SOCKET s;

    printf("\nInitialising Winsock...");
    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2),&wsa) != 0)
    {
        printf("Failed. Error Code : %d",WSAGetLastError());
        return 1;
    }

    printf("Initialised.\n");

    if((s = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , 0 )) == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        printf("Could not create socket : %d" , WSAGetLastError());
    }

    printf("Socket created.\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That is not a socket specific function.  My guess is you some other basic windows library.

Comment: Are you sure this is a build error?  That looks more like a source-level debugger trying to trace through operating system or at least library source code, which would not normally be available on a closed platform like Windows.  Also, is that pragma **really** how you tell this toolchain to link in a library?

Answer (score 1):

@user3139957 -- "*The error in compiler says: No source available for* `ntdll!KiFastSystemCallRet()`"

I really doubt that.  That is a system call from deep inside the kernel.  Do you mean the ***debugger*** said that?  Maybe eclipse has crashed and the debugger is trying to take over?

I presume you are using Visual C++, but what version?  Can you capture the output as text or as an image?

As an aside, the third parameter to socket() would be better as IPPROTO_TCP or IPPROTO_UDP, rather than 0.

Other than that, it looks fine.